# Comparison between 3-address instructions and 2-addresses instructions

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I saw both 3-address instructions and 2 address instructions are used as IR between front-end and back-end, what's the advantage and disadvantage for each of them because they are so similar?

Answer (score 1):

Three address is a form that shows the main principle of SSA, that intermediate are always immutable. (if you always allocate a new virtual register for a new intermediate).

Of course machine based allocators can easily convert and work with other forms too. Three address code is just an overviewable and easy way to model and explain SSA.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that 2 address and 3 address instruction sets are wildly different.  There are a lot of factors that can come into play in determining which to use.

- Code complexity vs code size.  Less operands means each individual instruction is easier to represent and implement.  More operands means more functionality can be represented by a single instruction.  Take the following comparison example:

> ```
> +---------------------------------------------------------
> | C instruction  | 2 address | 3 address   | 4 address   |
> +----------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
> | r = x;         | mov r,x   | mov r,x     | mov r,x     |
> +----------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
> | r = x + y;     | mov r,x   | add r,x,y   | add r,x,y,0 |
> |                | add r,y   |             |             |
> +----------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
> | r = x + y + z; | mov r,x   | add q,x,y   | add r,x,y,z |
> |                | add r,y   | add r,q,z   |             |
> |                | add r,z   |             |             |
> +----------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+
> ```

- Ease of optimization.  As previously mentioned, instruction sets with 3+ address counts allow for SSA implementation and analysis, which greatly simplifies many compile time optimizations.
- Ease of translation to target code.  This depends on what you are translating your IR to.  Translating 4 address code to a stack based language would be a hassle.  Translating 2 address code to a general purpose CISC architecture (like x86 assembly) would probably result in very inefficient code.